# dijkstra function of orientdb is not working with tinkerpop API

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

The below code is not giving the correct result, am I doing something wrong..?

```
OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();

for (OrientVertex v : (Iterable<OrientVertex>) graph.command(
                new OCommandSQL("SELECT dijkstra(#97:1334, #97:1335, 'calculated_length') FROM STRUCTURE")).execute()) {
                      System.out.println("Path " + (ORID)v.getId());
                    }
```

When I execute the query directly, I am getting correct result. Thanks.

Comment: What version of orientDb are you using ?

Comment: orientdb-community-2.2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this code and it worked

```
String query = "select expand(dijkstra) from (SELECT dijkstra(#21:0, #24:0, 'calculated_length') FROM STRUCTURE limit 1)";
Iterable<OrientVertex> it = g.command( new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();
for (OrientVertex v : it) { 
    System.out.println("Path " + (ORID)v.getId());     
}
```

Hope it helps